# DefaultAssetImageLocation on RichHtmlField being ignored

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, publishing

I am trying to set a centralised location for Site Collection Images and Assets via the Page Content field on a Publishing Page in SharePoint 2013.

According to the MSDN documentation.

[How to: Customize the Asset Picker in SharePoint Server 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms543215%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> You can define a custom picker shortcut for a RichHtmlField control or for a RichImageField control inside a page layout:
>
> 1. Navigate to \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\PublishingLayouts\PageLayouts and open a page layout .aspx file.
> 2. Find the Publishing field control associated with the control that uses the asset picker. For example,  represents the HTML Editor field control.
> 3. Add one or both of the following attributes to this tag:
>
>    **DefaultAssetLocation**: Defines the URL for the custom shortcut in a URL picker.
>
>    **DefaultAssetImageLocation**: Defines the URL for the custom shortcut in an image picker.
>
>    These URLs should be site collection–relative URLs pointing to a library, list, or other location in your site collection, such as /ReusableContent.
>
>    For example, the following  control defines the custom shortcuts /URLpicker and /imagepicker for URL and image pickers, respectively.
>
>    `<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="Content" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" DefaultAssetLocation="/URLpicker" DefaultAssetImageLocation= "/imagepicker" runat="server"/>`
>
>    Similarly, the following  control defines a custom shortcut for its image picker.
>
>    `<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="Content" FieldName="PublishingPageImage" DefaultAssetImageLocation="/imagepicker" runat="server"/>`
> 4. Save changes and close the page layout .aspx file.

I have been able to set the default location with no problems on a RichImageField control using the below code

`<PageFieldRichImageField:RichImageField 
    FieldName="543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac"
    DefaultAssetImageLocation="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/SiteCollectionImages/ %>"
    runat="server" />`

*Note*: $SPUrl is being used in my above example, this was required for me to get it to work. Ref: [Using DefaultAssetImageLocation propery of RichImageField in Page Layout](http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/34/Using-DefaultAssetImageLocation-propery-of-RichImageField-in-Page-Layout)

However, adding either `DefaultAssetImageLocation` or `DefaultAssetLocation` to a RichHtmlField does not change the behaviour of the insert Picture command on the SharePoint Ribbon.

If the user chooses Insert -> Picture -> From SharePoint using the Ribbon, I would expect the Asset picker to use the value set in the `DefaultAssetImageLocation` property on the RichHtmlField control, but it doesn't seem to.

Has anyone been able to get this to work in SharePoint 2013 or have used a workaround?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find any solution to this ?